# Buttons don't make Ajax request but reload page Rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new with ajax with rails so here is the problem.
I have method in controller :multi =>

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

The view for metod

```
<ul id="actions">
    <%= @game.user.actions %>
</ul>

<%= button_link_to "call", drid(:anchor => "opponents", :action => :call, :remote => true), :class => 'button' %>
<%= button_link_to "check", drid(:anchor => "opponents", :action => :check, :remote => true), :class => 'button' %>
```

`@game.user.actions` are in the database.

Here is ajax template

```
$("#actions").append("<%= escape_javascript @game.user.actions %>");
$("#new_action")[0].reset();
```

Problem is next: when I click on the buttons they add a new events to the list of actions
(e.g. ["call", "call", "call", "call", "check", "call", "call", "check", "check", "check", "call", "call"]), but the page is still reloading without any asynchronus request.

Please help as you can! any answers would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `e.preventDefault();` in the JS click-handler for button

Comment: $('.button').bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});